# Usage data not showing after importing data

Tags: getstream-io

After performing two successful imports (one for users and one for follow relationships) the usage data view has not updated with the expected values. Does this mean my records were not created from the import?

I was expecting around 50k user records with as many follow relationships.

Currently, I'm just creating user records as only having their ID set. When I do this via the api `get_or_create` I can see the usage update in real time. However, doing this via an import appears to have had no effect? Same for follow relationships.

I've noticed in the docs that it states `An array of users in which each line can have up to 10,000 entries`, does that mean I'm limited to 10k users per instruction?

Comment: Your interpretation of the note in the docs is correct. You just need to split into different instructions if you have more than 10K.

Comment: Thanks @ferhatelmas I will try again keeping them down to 10k per line. The import process doesn't seem to include this in its validation, as I was able to import "successfully" with a larger amount

Comment: It's interesting because it's in place and it would fail.

Comment: Also, you can write on support since this problem might not be a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: Sure thing @ferhatelmas. Is that just to an email address? I'm on a tier that only has community support

Comment: https://getstream.io/support will create a ticket for you to follow up. Self service import should work but if there is a problem and we fix it then it's a win for you and a win for us.

Comment: Thanks @ferhatelmas. I've raised a ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some details about what the issue was.

Automatic import has a config to disable tracking statistics for dashboard.

This configuration exists to support very big imports. However, automatic import limited by 300MB by default and it doesn't need to disable it because it's a manageable amount without any care.

That's why running configuration was wrong and it's enabled now.